# How to disable the Google auto-account detection on Sign In button?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

So a user installs my app. He logs in with `x@gmail.com`. Logs out. Then, he decides he want to log in with `y@gmail.com` instead. So he presses on the Google Sign In button. But, it automatically signs him in with `x@gmail.com` instead of creating the account chooser dialog.

**What I'd expect** is that everytime he wants to log-in with Google, it asks him which account to use. However after logging in once, then logging out, it doesn't ask which account to sign in with and just uses the previous email.

Here's my Firebase logout code:

```
try {
File dir = context.getCacheDir();
deleteDir(dir);
} catch (Exception ignored) {}
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
sweetAlertDialog.dismiss();
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, SignUp.class));
```

How can I prevent this?

Comment: @qbix I've spent HOURS looking and found nothing! Thanks!

Comment: This is how firebase works. You can only assign 1 sign-in method, firebase has documentation on this . A simple test : A user uses same email in facebook and google. Signs in to a firebase project from Google, then tries to login from facebook, he would see a google signin prompt even after confirming facebook signin.